# Cloud Firestore query with Variable in Where clause isn't working. Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have declared a global variable and defined it in the `initState()` function of the app.

But when later using that variable in the Where clause of the Cloud Firestore query, the query doesn't work:

> `.where("email", isEqualTo: _userEmail.toString())`

Instead, the query works when used with quotes:

> `.where("email", isEqualTo: "myemail@xyz.com")`

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Matrimonial').where("email", isEqualTo: _userEmail.toString()).getDocuments();
```

Not Working

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Matrimonial').where("email", isEqualTo: "myemail@xyz.com").getDocuments();
```

Working

Comment: post you `setState`method

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Dec 2021, seems to still be an issue...

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of using a varible parameter in the where clause by using vuefire:

```js
watch: {
    userProfile () {
      this.$bind('allUsers', this.$db.collection('users').where('institution', '==', this.userProfile.institution))
    }
  }
```

This case, as different admins log in and become the currentUser, then they can only see all of the users from their institution.

Answer (score 0):

Late to respond, but I was searching or an answer to this question, and using string interpolation worked for me:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Matrimonial').where("email", isEqualTo: `${_userEmail.toString()}`).getDocuments();
```

Comment: This method doesn't work for me. There is a syntax error on the backtick quotation.

Comment: Thanks @KatherineChen -- odd that this worked for me. Where do you see the error?