# Cloud Firestore query with Variable in Where clause is not working. Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]       class SetFirebaseDataSourceImpl implements SetFirebaseDataSource {

```
         final FirebaseFirestore firestore;
          SetFirebaseDataSourceImpl(this.firestore);
         @override
         Future<List<SetModel>> getAllSet(String subjectId) async {
             var data = await firestore
           .collection('set')
           .where('subjectId', isEqualTo: subjectId)
           .get();
            return data.docs.map((e) {
              var a = e.data();
              print('set $a');
              print(a);
               return SetModel.fromJson(a);
             }).toList();


          }
       }
```

it is not fetch document from firestore
and when replace "mathId" in place of subjectId it workfine

> **when we remove variable (subjectId) and write actual value then it works fine**
> [Cloud Firestore query with Variable in Where clause isn't working. Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946625/cloud-firestore-query-with-variable-in-where-clause-isnt-working-flutter)

Comment: Share what is shown in your terminal.

Comment: https://github.com/pks050505/polyteck-demo

Comment: This is your code, I want to see the error in your terminal

Comment: error not show  in terminal

Comment: same issue face above another asked question link above

Comment: As it seemds to work with `mathId`: Is there an actual field `subjectId` in the database? Show an extract of your database, please.

Comment: Added one image where you assume mathid with physicsid

Answer (score 1):

you missed `instance`
You wrote this

```
class SetFirebaseDataSourceImpl implements SetFirebaseDataSource {

     final FirebaseFirestore firestore;
      SetFirebaseDataSourceImpl(this.firestore);
     @override
     Future<List<SetModel>> getAllSet(String subjectId) async {
         var data = await firestore
       .collection('set')
       .where('subjectId', isEqualTo: subjectId)
       .get();
        return data.docs.map((e) {
          var a = e.data();
          print('set $a');
          print(a);
           return SetModel.fromJson(a);
         }).toList();


      }
   }
```

it is supposed to be this

class SetFirebaseDataSourceImpl implements SetFirebaseDataSource {

```
 final FirebaseFirestore firestore;
  SetFirebaseDataSourceImpl(this.firestore);
 @override
 Future<List<SetModel>> getAllSet(String subjectId) async {
     var data = await firestore.instance
   .collection('set')
   .where('subjectId', isEqualTo: subjectId)
   .get();
    return data.docs.map((e) {
      var a = e.data();
      print('set $a');
      print(a);
       return SetModel.fromJson(a);
     }).toList();


  }
```

}

Your code is okay.

Comment: No, I've initialize firestore in main.dart file

Comment: I'm not talking about that i'm saying that you missed calling `firestore.instance`

Comment: It is not problem of initialization